# Return row with value exist in both rows

Tags: mysql, sql

```
+------+------+------------+------+
| id   | type| design| location   |
+------+------+------------+------+
|    1 | abc |    A  | Location X |
|    2 | abc |    A  | Location Y |
|    3 | def |    A  | Location X |
+------+------+------------+------+
```

I have table like above.

Let say i want to get type where exist in Location X AND Y. It should return row 1 and 2.

what sql should i use?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT type
FROM    tableName
WHERE   location IN ('location x','location y')
GROUP   BY type
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6862/3)

or if you want to have all those values, use `JOIn`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
          SELECT  type
          FROM    tableName
          WHERE   location IN ('location x','location y')
          GROUP   BY type
          HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
        ) b ON a.type = b.type
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6862/4)

SOURCE

- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE type IN(SELECT type
              FROM table1
              WHERE location IN('location X', 'location y')
              GROUP BY type
              HAVING COUNT(type) = 2
             );
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c67c/2)

This will give you:

```
| ID | TYPE | DESIGN |   LOCATION |
-----------------------------------
|  1 |  abc |      A | Location X |
|  2 |  abc |      A | Location Y |
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to retrieve the type that exists in both you should do

```
    select [type] 
    from ur_table 
    where location = 'Location X'
    intersect 
    select [type] 
    from ur_table 
    where location = 'Location Y'
```

but if you realy need all data from the 2 rows.. try

```
    select id,[type],design, location 
    from ur_table L
    where L.[type] in (select [type] from ur_table where location = 'Location X'
                       intersect select [type] from ur_table where location = 'Location Y'
                       )
```